# Android onActivityResult() with Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to set the text when I press enter on the first screen so it looks like the second image. Whenever I try to set text nothing shows up on the second screen. I've partially taken out some of the code in the first activity because they are irrelevant.

[image]
[image]

My first activity

```
public class ActivityLoaderActivity extends Activity {

    static private final int GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    private void startExplicitActivation() {

        Log.i(TAG,"Entered startExplicitActivation()");

        Intent explicitIntent = null;
        explicitIntent = new Intent(ActivityLoaderActivity.this, ExplicitlyLoadedActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(explicitIntent, GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE);
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Entered onActivityResult()");
        if (requestCode == GET_TEXT_REQUEST_CODE) {
            // Make sure the request was successful
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                String value = (String) data.getExtras().getString("userInputMessage");
                mUserTextView.setText(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My second activity
    public class ExplicitlyLoadedActivity extends Activity {

```
    static private final String TAG = "Lab-Intents";

    private EditText mEditText;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.explicitly_loaded_activity);

        // Get a reference to the EditText field
        mEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

        // Declare and setup "Enter" button
        Button enterButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.enter_button);
        enterButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            // Call enterClicked() when pressed

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                enterClicked();

            }
        });

    }

    // Sets result to send back to calling Activity and finishes

    private void enterClicked() {

        Log.i(TAG,"Entered enterClicked()");

        //Save user provided input from the EditText field
        mEditText.toString();

        Intent resultIntent = new Intent();
        resultIntent.putExtra("userInputMessage ", "mEditText" );

        setResult(RESULT_OK, resultIntent);

        finish();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One obvious issue is that you are setting the string content to the literal `"mEditText"` instead of `mEditText.getText().toString()`, which would have the actual contents of the `EditText`:

```
resultIntent.putExtra("userInputMessage ", "mEditText" );
```

And then:

```
String value = (String) data.getExtras().getString("userInputMessage");
```

The next issue is that there is a space after `userInputMessage` in the first call, so that won't match when you try to get the extra data back later.

Better would be to define that as a `public static final String` value somewhere and use the reference in both places.

Comment: Thanks it's working. Do you mean define value with public static final string? Why?

Comment: Defining the string as a constant value instead of duplicating the string literal inline in your code would have prevented the bug in your application. There are numerous good reasons to avoid duplicate string literals in code, I suggest Googling for it you're unfamiliar with the idea.